# Unhandled Rejection (UnknownErrorException): The API version "2.0.91" does not match the Worker version "1.10.97"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, pdf

Got this error while trying to add PDF file into my website locally.

I have create one component called 'ViewPDF.jsx' and code for 'ViewPDF.jsx' is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Page } from "react";
import { Document } from 'react-pdf/build/entry.webpack';
import  PDF  from 'react-pdf-js';

import { Resume } from '../Download/Resume.pdf';

class ViewPDF extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page: 0,
      pages: 2
    };

    this.onDocumentComplete = this.onDocumentComplete.bind(this);
    this.onPageComplete = this.onPageComplete.bind(this);
  }

  onDocumentComplete(pages) {
    this.setState({ page: 1, pages });
  }

  onPageComplete(page) {
    this.setState({ page });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PDF file="{Resume}"/>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ViewPDF;
```

And I have created page under src/screen/Contact.jsx

Code for 'Contact.jsx' is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.jsx";
import Footer from "../components/Footer.jsx";
import Jumbotron from "../components/Jumbotron.jsx";
import { Document } from "react-pdf";
import ViewPDF from "../components/ViewPDF.jsx";

class Contact extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Jumbotron title="welcome" subtitle="put something" />
        <div className="container">
          <h2>Contact Me</h2>
          <p>
            Email Address: &nbsp;
            <a
              href="mailto:abc4@gmail.com?Subject=Hello"
              target="_top"
            >
              Click here for my Email Address
            </a>
          </p>

          <p>
            Click here for my resume!
            <a href="../Download/Resume.pdf">resume</a>
          </p>

          <ViewPDF />
        </div>

        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Contact;
```

My PDF file is saved locally under src/Download/Resume.pdf.

I am newbie to React. When I open page in Chrome I got this error message:

*Unhandled Rejection (UnknownErrorException): The API version "2.0.91" does not match the Worker version "1.10.97"*

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what if you reinstall  react-pdf-js? `npm uninstall -S react-pdf-js` , then `npm install -S react-pdf-js`

Comment: I tried uninstall and then re-install as you mentioned, but it still gives me the same error.